# JSON and web service safety

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services

I know there are numerous questions similar to this but I have more than 1 and I would really like answers and problem specific advise please.

I have created an ASP.NET app which accesses (reads and writes to) a SQL Server database via a web service.

I use JSON to call the webservice to populate Javascript graphs/charts.

Due to the requirements of the application i use ALOT of JSON.

Questions:

1. I use forms authentication so am I right in saying only successfully logged in users will ever be able to view the web pages source ?
2. If yes then the logged in user will be able to see my service path and could easily access privileged information, I have thought of adding a parameter (username) to each [WebMethod] to authenticate the request, would this be a good idea ?
3. Would it be wise to ONLY have the graph/chart methods on the service and for the rest of my requirements access the database directly from the web app (C# code behind).

I apologize in advance if the questions are stupid or aren't clear, but I really don't want to spend so much time creating an app that has a massive security flaw.

Thanks in advance for any advice/help or links

Comment: When you use ajax in code, you should assume that the path to the service is public for everyone. Therefore, you need to provide some security in your WebService.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid passing the user name and/or password in the ajax request, especially if not secured by SSL.  Use the authentication cookies provided by Forms Authentication, and check them on the server side.

One shortcut I've used is to create an empty .aspx page to receive the ajax requests.  Be sure to leave out the master page, if you have one.  The page has no markup, but can read the request variables, user info, session variables, etc, in the Page_Load. Then Response.Write the desired JSON output.  Something like this:

**MySearch.aspx.cs**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         // Check if user is logged in, and return JSON result of search
         if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
         {
             string json = MySearch(Request["Search"], Session["Language"]);
             Response.Clear();
             Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
             Response.Write(json);
             Response.End();
         }
   }
```

This way you don't have to expose a whole web service interface to the public.  You've got a simple way to "check out" the user before returning the JSON.

If you have unauthenticated requests redirecting to a login page, you may need to leave this page available to unathenticated users, hence, the check in code for IsAuthenticated.  Unauthenticated users will get just an empty html page, which may break the javascript logic, so test for that.